# Removing Fruit From Secondary

Tags: secondary-fermentation, sanitation, fruit

I recently brewed a peach hefeweizen and I added 7lb of fresh peaches to the secondary.  I just chunked the peaches and popped them into the carboy.  I have siphoned the beer out for bottling and now I am left with a carboy full of peach chunks!  What's the best way for getting these out?  I was thinking about just soaking them with some PBW and then maybe mashing them up a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your carboy glass or plastic? If you're using a plastic carboy you definitely don't want to go mashing things around inside because you'll run the risk of scratches. Bacteria hide in scratches.

I'd recommend adding some OxyClean or PBW, some hot (not boiling!) water, and shaking up the carboy until the fruit pieces break up into smaller ones that will pour out. Fruit that has been soaking in liquid for a long time is going to be pretty soft and should break up fairly easily.

Comment: I use glass, but that's good advice regarding the scratches in plastic.  I ended up using PBW and soaking it overnight.  It pretty much broke up on its own after that.  I am going to give you the answer because of the scratches comment.

Answer (score 0):

I found the fruit to be fairly soft already. I used a short, hard plastic stick to help me get them out. Mashing them up a little first might help.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a bottle/carboy washer (little attachment you can put on your faucet) and a carboy brush to be invaluable in cleanup.